# Windows Power Plans for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance-tuning, windows-server

Is the High Performance power plan in Windows Server still relevant in SQL Server setups on modern hardware/virtualization? Searching for articles from my usual trusted sources brought up nothing more recent than 4 years ago. As a rule of thumb, I've used High Performance Power Plan on SQL Server setups since my early days as a DBA, and as I'm taking inventory in a shop I'm new to, I've found several production servers still running the default Balanced power plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While some hardware vendors say that modern hardware behaves snappier on Balanced Power Plan it is still rule of the thumb to use High Performance plan for production servers.

Power plans are still checked by various popular community tools, like [sp_Blitz](http://firstresponderkit.org/) in First Responder Kit or [Test-DbaPowerPlan](https://dbatools.io/) from DBATools.io

While there are no new articles strictly about SQL Server on this topic, Microsoft has good article about power and performance tuning in Windows Server 2016+: [Power and performance tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/hardware/power/power-performance-tuning)

Comment: It was actually through perusing the DBATools documentation that I was reminded about Power Plans impact on performance. :) That's what happens when you leave one shop where you baked it into your base Windows Server VM templates.